# the Mahlo operation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What is the strongest (in the consistency strength sense) cardinal $\kappa$
for which it is consistent (with ZFC) (or not known to be inconsistent) that there is a cardinal $\lambda$ with stationary many $\kappa$ cardinals below $\lambda$?

Comment: The question is odd. Any such cardinal $\kappa$, you can now replace it by $\lambda$. Remember that "a proper class of supercompact cardinals" is much weaker than "an inaccessible cardinal which is a limit of supercompact cardinals". Even if the latter does not even postulate there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a student only. What exactly do we get by replacing $\kappa$ by $\lambda$?

Comment: If there is an inaccessible with stationary many X below it, then postulating "There is an inaccessible with stationarily many cardinals, each has stationarily many X below it" is much stronger.

Comment: Do I understand it right, that it is always much stronger but **not** known to be inconsistent and thereby forming a never ending hierarchy?

Comment: **We don't know**. You're asking if I, or collectively we, know some proof of inconsistency of a property being "unbounded" but not "bounded". This is a ridiculously difficult question to ask in modern set theory. It's not a bad question, don't get me wrong, it's an obvious question that most people in set theory probably wonder about at one point or another. The answer is just "we can't really know, can we?". It's like asking "Is the existence of inaccessible cardinals consistent?", and the answer can only be "assuming *what* meta-theory?"

Comment: I was aware about this while I was asking that question. I just hoped that some terribly strong large cardinal property will already yield inconsistency with this Mahlo operation. You say that it is not that case. I'm satified with this.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not the case. I'm saying that the question is naive, and from a formal point of view, ill-formed.

Comment: Assume that you work in the theory "ZFC+No inaccessible cardinal is the limit of inaccessible cardinals", then inaccessible cardinals are probably somewhere close to what you're asking about.

Comment: All of my confusion was due to the fact that I used syntax where I should have used semantics, is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Your "No inaccessible cardinal is the limit of inaccessible cardinals" is a semantic statement: we must have either this or its negation. On the part of syntax we do not need decide this.

Comment: No, that's an axiom, which in principle I can add to ZFC (and without adding contradictions, too!), and then I can claim that I insist working in this theory. So I'd tell you that inaccessible cardinal is the highest you can go. Can you refute that? I don't see how.

Comment: I can't make grammatical sense of "stationary many $\kappa$ cardinals  below ...". What is a $\kappa$ cardinal?

Comment: It is a type of a cardinal. Say strongly inaccessible, weakly inaccessible, etc. But Asaf Karagila has already explained to me that the question is odd.